# Django test user password

Tags: django

I have written a REST API for updating a user's password. Since it is impossible to unhash the password stored by django, how am I suppose to test my API besides asserting the response status_code?

Comment: You can test it that it worked (status code) and that you can login with the new password.

Comment: ...you can login with the new password and you can't login with the old one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check a user's `password` with `User.check_password(password_to_check)`. This will `return True` if the `password` is correct. (see documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password))

Note that if you have created a user in your unit test and then change a `password` for the user, you need to update the user reference before you can see the new `password`, like this:

```
// create self.user 
// change the password to "newpassword"
self.user = User.objects.get(username="username")  # get user again so that you can see updated password
self.assertEquals(self.user.check_password("newpassword"), True)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create the following assertions in the test_password_update test:

- 1. user login
- 2. password update
- 3. user login

If the user is able to login after the password update, then you are safe and the API works correctly.